# Backbone collection on events

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a collection set on my view. I'd like to render any time the collection is changed. However, it appears that according to the Backbone API docs 'change' isn't a valid event for a collection. So I've currently got `this.collection.on('add reset remove');` which isn't really ideal.

What's the recommended way to handle this? Is there a standard way to track all changes to a collection in Backbone?

Comment: Define "change" for us please, within the scenario you are looking at. Change does not fire when adding and removing models. Change does fire when attributes within models change... and that bubbles up to the collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use the `all` event. But why is what you have not ideal?
Also, the `change` event will bubble up to the collection, so you can use that as well. Although typically you wouldn't update a collection view, but individual subviews representing each item.

Comment: The reason why I feel it is not ideal is because I want to re-render the view on every change. While I agree with your statement about collections not typically having views, this is a some what bizarre case and it makes the most sense to a view that listens to and interacts with a collection.

Comment: If your collection view is rendering out all the models, and you want to update the view when any model changes, you can use the `change` event, as I mentioned, which bubbles up to the collection.

Answer (score 1):

Collection don't have `change` events on their own. Although, they bubble the change events of their models.

So you can do:

```
this.collection.on("change");
// Or better
this.listenTo(collection, "change");
```

Relevant documentation: http://backbonejs.org/#Collection